# passing member function of one class to a member function of another class - segfault - mrmpi

Tags: c++, mapreduce, parameter-passing

**Edit:**

I tried implementing a minimal code for this and it worked. I'm back to my code trying to figure out what is wrong there. This question was wrong from the beginning, leaving it for future references with corrected minimal code (or should I delete it?)

```
#include <iostream>

class LibClass {
public:
        int mapLibClass( void (*callbackfunc) ( int, void*)) {
            std::cout << " in map " << std::endl;
            callbackfunc(8,NULL);
        }
};

class MyClass {
public:
        LibClass* objLibClass;

        MyClass(LibClass* objLibClass) : objLibClass(objLibClass) { }

        void runLibClass() {
            std::cout << "in runLibClass" << std::endl;
            objLibClass -> mapLibClass(&MyClass::callbackfunc);
        }
        static void callbackfunc(int i, void* ptr) {
            std::cout << "in callback" << std::endl;
        }
};

int main() {
        LibClass* libClassObj = new LibClass();
        MyClass myClassObj(libClassObj);
        myClassObj.runLibClass();
        return 0;
}
```

---

I'm working with mrmpi library (no need to know the library as the problem is explained below but it is an implementation of MapReduce for C++). The library accepts callback functions as arguments to its member functions:

```
class LibClass {
public:
    int mapLibClass( void (*callbackfunc)(int, KV*, void*)) { }
};
```

Now I have my own class, that has a member variable of the (pointer to) LibClass type and needs to call the mapLibClass function of this variable passing in a function of my class to it.

```
class MyClass {
public:
    LibClass* objLibClass;

    MyClass(LibClass objLibClass) : objLibClass(objLibClass) { }

    void runLibClass() {
        //I have some extra lines here checking to make sure other member variables and also objLibClass are set correctly
        objLibClass -> mapLibClass(&MyClass::callbackfunc);
    }

    static void callbackfunc(int i, KV* kv, void* ptr) {
        //just an std::cout here to make sure I get into this function
    }
};

int main() {
    LibClass* libClassObj = new LibClass();
    MyClass myClassObj(libClassObj);
    myClassObj.runLibClass();
    return 0;
}
```

Everything goes smoothly until mapLibClass is called from inside runLibClass function. mapLibClass is supposed to do some stuff and then call the callback function that it accepts as a parameter. But when I'm running my program it never enters the callback function but I get a segmentation fault.

If I make the callbackfunc a non-member function, the program runs correctly, so it has something to do with passing in a member function. I have read the documentation and other SO posts but all I see is that my member callbackfunc should be static (which it is or it wouldn't even compile), or I should use boost::bind and boost::function (which requires me to change the library source code). I can't figure out what is causing the segfault. Any help is highly appreciated as I have spent too much time on this. Thanks.

Comment: don't compile and can't reproduce http://ideone.com/trITGM

Comment: There's no difference between non-member and static member functions. After fixing obvious errors your example [works](http://ideone.com/IJredv). Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Sorry about that. I started writing a minimal code after the first comment: http://ideone.com/70THz8 ... and... it runs now. I should look for the problem somewhere else I guess.

Answer (score -1):

Between when you are passing member function as parameter you need to have different declaration.
There is a small example below, which might help you.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {
public:
  void xx() { cout << "xx" << endl; }
};

void f(A &a, void (A::*x)()) {
  (a.*x)();
  cout << "calling A xx" << endl;
}

int main() {
  // your code goes here
  A a;
  f(a, &A::xx);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: "Between when you are passing member function as parameter you need to have different declaration." Err... what?

Comment: I changed the code to make it run as it was not compiling (pointed out by Stargateur). And realized it works, so problem should be somewhere else. Sorry about that. ideone.com/70THz8

Answer (score -2):

looks like you ctor should receive a pointer instead of the class by value.
that's why you get seg fault beacuse your pointer is null.
the following change will solve your problem:

```
MyClass(LibClass * objLibClass) : objLibClass(objLibClass) {}
```

Comment: It's can't be this, `MyClass(LibClass objLibClass) : objLibClass(objLibClass) {}` don't compile.

Comment: The compiler would of screamed (There's probably no cast, and if there is it wouldn't have nulled the pointer ), it's probably just a typo from the op trying to create a mvce.

Comment: I changed the code to make it run as it was not compiling (pointed out by Stargateur). And realized it works, so problem should be somewhere else. Sorry about that. http://ideone.com/70THz8